# Telephone validate number but allow international + sign

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, validation, form-validation

In our `checkout_index_index.xml` file we use the following code.
This works well to validate if the input is a number, but it does not allow the international sign `+` followed by the country code. How can we allow the `+` sign also as a valid number input.

CODE:

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">500</item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="validate-number" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">12</item>
        </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free extension and add country code dynamically in the telephone field,
https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input

NOTE: Inside `Block/PhoneNumber.php` file comment or remove this line, `"preferredCountries" => [$this->helper->preferedCountry()]` then it works perfectly.

Comment: This telephone extension not working proper.
getting error in telephone.html

Comment: Can you provide details about the error? and which version of Magento did you check?